# Confused about js proto and assigning new properties

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, prototype

I have a simple object (a button in Sencha Touch actually). It's in an object called 'something.aButton()';

This object contains a property called 'view' with a value of 'home';

Now I want to assign this to a variable, assign some new properties and pass it on.

So I do:

```
var c = something.aButton();
```

Now I assign some more stuff:

```
c.id = 4;
c.class = 'class';
```

Now the problem is that c.view is undefined unless I do:

```
c.view = c.view;
```

Which - coming from a PHP world baffles the heck out of me. I get the basics of prototypes but don't understand how I can simply assign my object to a variable for ease of use and work from that. I don't know all the original properties either so reassigning it like this is not possible in my code and I somehow doubt that this is the proper way.

If I dump 'c' to my console I see:

```
Ext.Object.classify.objectClass
class: "class"
id: 4
__proto__: Object
  view: 'home'
  ....
```

Comment: Your assertion that `c.view = c.view;` effects a change in the value of `c.view` is incorrect. I can't tell you what's behind the odd behavior you're seeing because it's not clear what that is, and I'm not a Sencha touch expert (or even familiar with it).

Comment: There's something else wrong... while `c.view = c.view` can copy the property from a prototype of `c` to the current instance of `c`, it doesn't make it defined if it was undefined before, since reading a property does walk the prototype chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I assign some more stuff:
>
> ```
> c.id = 4;
> c.class = 'class';
> ```

I would avoid using the identifier `class`. It's a reserved word in the 3rd edition of JavaScript, and in "loose" (non-strict) code in the 5th edition.

> Now the problem is that c.view is undefined unless I do:
>
> ```
> c.view = c.view;
> ```

It's not undefined. What you're changing there is whather `c` has its *own* copy of the `view` property. If you just did `console.log(c.view)` you'd see its value in the console, even without doing the assignment above.

The way prototypes work in JavaScript is that the object is backed up by the prototype in a **live** way. So if you take the value of `view` from `c`, and `c` doesn't have its *own* property called `view`, its prototype chain is checked. But if you *assign* a value to `view` on `c`, then `c` gains a property of its *own* with that name, and you see it in object dumps and such.

So here's a simplified example:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.bar = "42";

var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.bar); // "42"
```

At the moment, our object graph looks like this:

```
+-----------+      +---------------+
|     f     |----->| Foo.prototype |
|-----------|      |---------------|
|           |      | bar: "42"     |
+-----------+      +---------------+
```

So there we have `f`, which is backed by the prototype `Foo.prototype`. When we ask `f` for the property `bar`, since `f` doesn't have a property of its own by that name, the JavaScript engine looks to its prototype to see if *it* does. If so, that value is used. (And this continues if the prototype has a prototype, etc.)

Now suppose we do this:

```
f.bar = "43";
console.log(f.bar); // "43"
```

Because `f` now has its *own* `bar` property, the JavaScript engine uses the value of that property. Now our graph looks like this:

```
+-----------+      +---------------+
|     f     |----->| Foo.prototype |
|-----------|      |---------------|
| bar: "43" |      | bar: "42"     |
+-----------+      +---------------+
```

We can *remove* `f`'s property:

```
delete f.bar;       // `delete` removes "own" properties from objects
console.log(f.bar); // "42"
```

...and so retrieving `bar` from `f` once again looks to the prototype, because `f` doesn't have a property called `bar`. We're back to the original object graph:

```
+-----------+      +---------------+
|     f     |----->| Foo.prototype |
|-----------|      |---------------|
|           |      | bar: "42"     |
+-----------+      +---------------+
```

Now the fun bit: Suppose we change *the prototype's* property?

```
Foo.prototype.bar = "baz";
console.log(f.bar); // "baz"
```

Because `f` doesn't have a `bar` property, the engine looks at the prototype. This is what I meant by it being a **live** system.

Comment: It's starting to make sense. I assume that I am required to do c.view = c.view because Sencha or some code I have must check if the value is set in current object or in its prototype.  So how can I make a new instance that has all of its values filled in just as the prototype does is the issue I am facing

Comment: @Joshua: You shouldn't have to do `c.view = c.view;` at all, I've never seen it in code in the wild, only artificial situations created to make a point. Code using `c` would have to make a special point of checking whether it has a `view` property of its own or is getting it from the prototype, and there are very few reasons to do that. The code using `c` should just retrieve `view` from it and not care where it comes from.

Comment: @Joshua: *"So how can I make a new instance that has all of its values filled in just as the prototype does is the issue I am facing"* If you really need to do that, just use a `for..in` loop, because that will loop over all of the enumerable properties of the object. `var newc, name; newc = {}; for (name in c) { newc[name] = c[name]; }` Now `newc` has all of the enumerable properties of `c` (regardless of where they come from). But again, there are very few reasons to do that.

Comment: Thanks - it is probably a peculiarity of the framework - I've resolved it some other way but thank you for your explanations